# Problema 403 Forbidden al añadir imágenes a botones en tkinter(Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy creando un programa y he creado un botón. A ese botón aún no le he asignado un comando. La cosa está en que al asignarle una imagen al botón, me sale este error:

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

También me salió esto anteriormente, pero ya no me acuerdo como lo solucioné.
Aquí está mi código:

```
register_new_classroomURL = "https://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Pencil-PNG.png"
register_new_classroom_upload = io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(register_new_classroomURL).read())
register_new_classroom_open = Image.open(register_new_classroom_upload)
register_new_classroom_open = register_new_classroom_open.resize((100,200))
register_new_classroom_show = ImageTk.PhotoImage(register_new_classroom_open)
register_new_classroom_button = Button(window, text="Registrar una nueva clase.", image=register_new_classroom_show, compound=BOTTOM)
register_new_classroom_button.place(x="0", y="1815")
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto comumente es debido a que el mod_security de la web está bloqueando tu petición, ya que al realizarlo de esta forma está detectando tu requerimiento como si la realizara un bot para scraping web y por esta razón se puede estar bloqueando, intenta agregar un buen header a la petición de esta forma no se detectará como un bot.

```
req = Request('tu_url', headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @joseluis18vs, ¡ya funciona!